# Why can I run `sudo bash` but not `sudo su`?

Tags: sudo

I am working on standardizing the sudo access in our environment. To begin with, I am understanding the current setup.

Currently, we use `sudo bash` to get into the root shell without typing any passwords. I understand that giving sudo access on individual commands is recommended but at least for now, I wanted a mechanism where we type our password and then get a root shell.

To re-iterate, `sudo bash` or `sudo -s` works fine but when I typed `sudo su -`, it prompted for my password and once I typed it, it gave me a message '*Sorry, user <username> is not allowed to execute '/bin/su -' as root on *lt;server name>'*. This got me curious to see how is `sudo bash` working.

In `/etc/sudoers` file, I see two lines relevant in this context:

```
        root    ALL=(ALL)   ALL
        %wheel  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

And I am not part of the `%wheel` group. `admin` is my default group in `/etc/passwd` and `admin` group isn't part of `wheel` group in `/etc/group`. So, to make `sudo su -` to work, I added below line to the `sudoers` file and it worked.

```
        %admin  ALL=(ALL)   ALL
```

But I am not able to understand:

- How is `sudo bash` working for everyone?
- Is everyone part of the `wheel` group by default?

Please let me know if I am missing something here. Also, if there are better ways to do things.

OS: CentOS 7.2 (Red Hat family)

---

It turns out there are certain files in `/etc/sudoers.d` and that's how `sudo bash` was working but i thought it was commented out... Thanks.

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: Are there any other configs included at the end of the `sudoers` file?

Comment: Ah right.. there are certain files in /etc/sudoers.d and that's how 'sudo  bash' was working but i thought it was commented out... Thanks.                                                                                              
                                                                                                                 
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d                                                                            From the sudoers man page:

Comment: And what's the recommended way to give full root access to sysadmins? (or if you want to say less harmful and audited way)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8581/117549

Answer (score 2):

Answer assembled from comments:

The issue of why `sudo bash` was working for someone not in the `wheel` group was resolved through the realization that the main `sudoers` configuration file was including further configuration files from `/etc/sudoers.d` (and one of these files allowed this to happen).

And yes, the `#` at the start of `#include` is confusing.

A further question regarding how to safely give super-user rights to system administrators was answered by referring to the old question "[Which is the safest way to get root privileges: sudo, su or login?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8581/which-is-the-safest-way-to-get-root-privileges-sudo-su-or-login)". As is evident from the answers to that question, it is not a matter that is straight forward.

Also related: "[Is there ever a good reason to run sudo su?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218169/is-there-ever-a-good-reason-to-run-sudo-su)"